# how can I change the colorscheme programmatically with vimscript?

Tags: variables, vim, neovim, color-scheme

I want to change the colorscheme inside a vimscript like:

```
let g:scheme = "default"
colorscheme scheme
```

and i get the following error:

```
colorscheme "scheme" cannot be found
```

why is the variable 'scheme' not linked to the string 'default' when i execute the :colorscheme command ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "vimscript" or "viml script" or whatever (naming is hard) is really just a sequence of Ex commands, sometimes called "colon commands".

Most of those commands, like `:colorscheme`, only take straight up strings as input and don't even try to evaluate variables/expressions:

```
colorscheme scheme
```

In your example, `scheme` is treated as a string, not as a variable so, of course, you get an error because you don't have a colorscheme called `scheme`.

In those cases, which are relatively common, variables must be evaluated before being passed to the Ex command. This is done with `:help :execute` and the `:help expr-..` operator:

```
execute 'colorscheme ' .. scheme
```